# Assets don't show on staging but do on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have this issue I can't figure out. I did some googling and I didn't find a suitable answer, so I am asking the community.

I have a Rails app with 4 environments: development, test, staging and production. Everything works great in development, test and production, but for some reason, the assets are not being served in staging.

Staging is a copy of production basically. I use Capistrano to deploy the site. The assets are being compiled on the server and are of type *asset-xxxxx.ext* on the server. This works as expected.

The scripts and stylesheets are also being used being compile in the same way (*application-xxxxx.css*, *application-xxxxx.js*). This also works as expected.

**Problem**

The *image-url* in my stylesheets are not changed to reflect the path set by sproket. For example, the file *sprite.png* was changed to *sprite-25d57a117a61de097e8f943ff745e8b0.png*, but the css remains *sprite.png*.

What is confusing is the *environments/staging.rb* is the same as *environments/production.rb* and I have no problem in production.

**Failures**

I have try to play with the following values:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

but nothing works. And as I said, the exact same setting work in production...

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

in staging.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

then run commad:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging rake assets:precompile
```

and push the compiled files with menifest file.

Hope it works!!!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Jeremie check my updated answer. Make `compile = true` and try again

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but no luck. It doesn't work.